# perl to php data passing

Tags: php, xml, json, perl, sqlite

i have a perl file and a php file.
i need to pass a big hash in the perl file to php.

The data generated by perl file needs to be stored in a file.
This php have to read this file and modify the same.
This modified file needs to read back by the perl and do some other operation.

The data to be shared is a perl hash which is really big and having lot of inner array also.

i have tried to store the hash to json and read it in php but i failled.

is there any other method for the same?

Comment: You can store datas in MongoDB

Comment: The string "i failled" is not a built-in error message in any programming language that I'm aware of.

Comment: There an unlimited number of ways. JSON is the simplest. Get help with your JSON problem.

Answer (score 1):

For having multiple sources accessing the same data store a database is the most typical option, thought a text file can work just the same.

So to answer your question - yes there are other methods for creating a communal data store - DBs and DB libraries, CSV, Excel, etc. For each choice you will need to become familiar with the perl and PHP api to access it - you may find it easier than fooling with a JSON in plain text.

Comment: Of course, if you were looking for specific help on your current project as-is, you would need to post code and exact error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [php serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and this [perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/PHP-Serialization-0.34/lib/PHP/Serialization.pm).
Its a easy way to exchange data structures as simple strings between the tow languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('my_data.json'), true);

# PROCESS DATA

file_put_contents('my_data.json',
                  preg_replace('/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e',
                               'iconv("UCS-4LE",
                                      "UTF-8",
                                       pack("V",
                                       hexdec("U$1")))',
                  json_encode($data)));
```

The preg_replace handles the ugly "\uXXXX"-sequences PHP usually outputs for unicode characters. If you have PHP 5.4+ this should work instead:

```
file_put_contents('my_data.json', json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

As mentioned in one of the other answers, consider using a database if you need to do a lot of reading and writing.